# Cant resolve method getwidth and getHeight

Tags: java, android

My Error is cannot resolve method `getWidth()`; and same for `getHeight()`;
I'm still new to android studio so please cut me some slack and please explain to me.

Note,the second `canvas.scale` is the added code i found that is supposed to be to solution to get the screen resolution.

Here's my code

```
       private void draw(){
           if(visible){
               Canvas canvas= holder.lockCanvas();
               canvas.save();


               movie.draw(canvas, -100, 0);
               canvas.restore();
               holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
               movie.setTime((int) (System.currentTimeMillis() % movie.duration()));
               handler.removeCallbacks(drawGif);
               handler.postDelayed(drawGif,frameDuration);

           }
       }



    @Override
    public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
        super.onVisibilityChanged(visible);
        this.visible=visible;
        if(visible){
            handler.post(drawGif);
        } else {
            handler.removeCallbacks(drawGif);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }



}
```

}

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention, but its cannot resolve method getWidth(); and getHeight();

Comment: you are calling getWidth() and getHeight on which element? Because is your current context I don't think this refers to what you think it does.

Comment: this refers to the canvas i changed that to canvas now and copied ajays code, the height is right but not the width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use canvas instead context like

```
 canvas.scale((float)canvas.getWidth() / (float)movie.width(),(float)canvas.getHeight() /      (float)movie.height());
```

Comment: no require for delete just try canvas instead this on error line

Comment: Thanks this works! butt do you know why it displays the gif more to the left? the height is perfect but the width is off

Comment: Have you notice your calculation? you are dividing width

Comment: How/Where would i fix this? sorry for my lack of knowledge, im still fairly new

Comment: Not an issue but how can i define logic for you? that is your own calculation for setting canvas scale so how can i do that?canvas.scale((float)canvas.getWidth() / (float)movie.width(),(float)canvas.getHeight() /      (float)movie.height());

Comment: Yes i found that code on here,  so its not my calculation,it works ,but for the width its not matched right, so would removing the "/" after get width and get height not divide it?

Comment: What operators could i use to make the canvas.getWidth equal to the movie.width? i repled the "/" with commas and that didnt work

Comment: you want to set the width of canvas equals to movie width?

Comment: Nevermind i solved it it was something with the code below it thanks btw thanks so much!